# ISO 8601 Year- and Week numbers

Tags: powerbi, dax, iso, week-number

I'm struggling with week sorting.
In details:
Measure for calculate weeks:

```
Year Week Column: =
CONCATENATE(
    YEAR ([Date]),
    " W" & FORMAT( WEEKNUM ([Date], 21), "00" )
)
```

[image: switch_years]

I cannot find a way to put 2023 W52 between 2022W52 and 2023 W01.
Can you advise me in this subject?
What should be the key to sort these weeks properly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a matter of sorting. It's a matter of properly applying the ISO week calendar logic, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).
Your formula for **Year Week Column** needs to consider that **2023-01-01** belongs to the ISO week year **2022** and here's how to calculate it:

```
Year Week Column = 
IF (
    WEEKNUM ( [Date], 21 ) = 1
        && MONTH ( [Date] ) = 12,
    YEAR ( [Date] ) + 1,
    IF (
        WEEKNUM ( [Date], 21 ) >= 52
            && MONTH ( [Date] ) = 1,
        YEAR ( [Date] ) - 1,
        YEAR ( [Date] )
    )
) 
& "-W" & FORMAT ( WEEKNUM ( [Date], 21 ), "0#" )
```

[image]

With a correct **Year Week Column** you don't have any issues with sorting!

Comment: Hi Peter
Thanks for reply.
I add another picture where you can see that I calculate weeks as return type = 21, so Week 52 contains dates from Dec 2022 and Jan 2023.

Comment: You're wrong: The ISO Week format for 2023-01-01 is 2022-W52-7, while you mistakenly calculate 2023-W52, see en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date: The corresponding example date is New Year 1978, which was a Sunday like in this year. You can use my above formula to get the proper result.

Comment: Nice solution Peter, thanks. I implemented this but replaced the nested `IF` with a `SWITCH` and shoved the `WEEKNUM ( [Date] , 21 )` into a variable to avoid having to evaluate the function call multiple times.